# How can I install nomachine over ssh on Suse (not openSuse)?

Tags: linux, nomachine

I have spent about 2 hours with no luck on this one. I want to use the NX protocol for remote desktop because it is much faster, so I hear, when going over the internet. And their client allows for me to easily restore disconnected sessions, another plus for flaky internet connections.

I download the latest from www.nomachine.com and it will not allow me to connect over port port 22. Port 22/ssh is my only option as arbitrary ports such as 4000 are blocked on the server which this is being installed on. I have tried downloading and installing the latest server versions on the linux machine but the main one, and enterprise version, do not allow ssh. I have also tried looking for previous versions such as 3.5 and cannot find an installer for that either. I looked through various freeNX sites and rpm repos but they all have deadlinks, readme.txt's stating the files are no hosted for some random reason, or point back to nomachine.com, which no longer has. I have spent about 2 hours on this total and feel like a major retard for trying to install something so seemingly trivial...

Answer (score 0):

So yeah it took awhile, but if it helps anyone else, this forum posts has 4 easy to run commands to get nxserver installed:

http://www.suse.in.th/how-tofaq-%28advanced-skill%29-42/install-freenx-on-sles-11/

```
# Download repository
wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/X11:/RemoteDesktop/SLE_11/X11:RemoteDesktop.repo

#Add a new repository
zypper ar X11:RemoteDesktop.repo

#Install
zypper in freenx

#Setup
nxsetup --install --setup-nomachine-key --clean
```

To configure it you may need to actually add the users yourself to get it to work:

```
nxserver --adduser bob
nxserver --passwd
...enter nx passwords at prompt
```